# How do i get the numbers from the List?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (LR.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LR.Count; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

LR is a List type of class.
In this List I have 15 indexes for example in index [0] I have:

```
[0] = {Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Region}
```

Now in this index[0] I have two int's variables end 88 and start 96

In this for loop up here what I need to do is:

```
if (LR.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LR.Count; i++)
    {
        _fts.Add(
    }
}
```

_fts is a `List<int>` what  I want is to add from each index in the LR List the two numbers.
So if I'm trying to do just:

```
_fts.Add(LR[I]);
```

I'm getting two errors:

> Error 31  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(int)' has some invalid arguments

And

> Error 32  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Region' to 'int'

How can I just get the two numbers from each index of the List LR and add this two numbers each time to the List _fts ?

Comment: Small note: You don't have to check whether `LR.Count` is bigger than 0 (unless there's more code outside the `for()` loop.

Comment: what is `LR` looks like?

Comment: If Im doing this:  _fts.Add(LR[i].end); then im not getting any errors or if im doing :  _fts.Add(LR[i].start); but I need to do something that will add each the end and start end and start of each index from LR and not to add only the end and then start. But to add each time a couple.

Comment: @JhonatanBirdy Could you include an example of how do you want `_fts` to look like after you finish?

Comment: spajce this is the build of LR: List<Lightnings_Extractor.Lightnings_Region> LR; it's a List of another class. It's a List of Lightnings_Region class. And each index of this class in the List contain two numbers: end and start. So if end is 44 and start is 40 so in _fts in index[0] I should see: 40 then 44 then 50 then 56 a list of numbers.

Comment: did you try to `_fts.Add(int.Parse(LR[i].ToString()))`?

Comment: _fts should be just simple List of numbers. 1 40 44 50 56 70 80 90 99...just a List with numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add `start` and then `end` to `_fts`, then try

```
for (int i = 0; i < LR.Count; i++)
{
  _fts.Add(LR[I].start);
  _fts.Add(LR[I].end);
}
```

If you want one entry in `_fts`, then you need another class to contain a `start` and `end` and redefine the _fts variable.

```
public class Range
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}

public List<Range> _fts = new List<Range>();

_fts.Add(new Range {Start = LR[I].start, End = LR[I].end} );
```

You should also use a `foreach` instead of `if` then `for`:

```
foreach (var lr in LR)
{
   _fts.Add(new Range {Start = lr.start, End = lr.end} );
}
```